# UnsupportedClassVersion Error: com/etrade/sesmgmt/SetCharacterEncodingFilter : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, java-8, java-7, tomcat6, tomcat8

I am upgrading an application from **JDK 1.7 to 1.8** and from **Tomcat 6 to tomcat 8**.
All Paths are correctly set for jdk 1.8

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersion Error: com/etrade/sesmgmt/SetCharacterEncodingFilter : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the full log of starting my server:

```
Oct 19, 2016 12:29:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_73/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_73/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_73/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin;D:\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
Oct 19, 2016 12:29:04 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:vyaparW' did not find a matching property.
Oct 19, 2016 12:29:04 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'disableURLRewriting' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
Oct 19, 2016 12:29:04 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:vyaparn' did not find a matching property.
Oct 19, 2016 12:29:05 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Oct 19, 2016 12:29:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 597 ms
Oct 19, 2016 12:29:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 19, 2016 12:29:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
Oct 19, 2016 12:29:05 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\CDAC\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\vyaparn\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 19, 2016 12:29:05 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry registerComponent
SEVERE: Null component Catalina:type=JspMonitor,name=jsp,WebModule=//localhost/vyaparn,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/etrade/sesmgmt/SetCharacterEncodingFilter : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.etrade.sesmgmt.SetCharacterEncodingFilter)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2531)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1010)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1483)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadClassAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationFilterAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1074)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4377)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
```

Comment: Sounds like you aren't actually running under Java 8 at the moment...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is still runing on tomcat 6 `INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26`. Check also JAVA_HOME it should use java 8

Comment: @piyush you should first migrate to a Tomcat version that is compatible with Java 8, then migrate to Java 8 (or do both at the same time). Do not try to migrate to Java 8 first as you will run into problems that are only due to your old Tomcat version.

Comment: Thanks... migrating to tomcat 8 and jdk 1.8 together worked.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing your compiler's compilation level to 1.8.